# Sending behavior within Akka messages

Tags: java, akka, actor

Straight from the Akka docs:

> Actors are made to be containers for behavior and state, embracing this means to not routinely send behavior within messages (which may be tempting using Scala closures). One of the risks is to accidentally share mutable state between actors, and this violation of the actor model unfortunately breaks all the properties which make programming in actors such a nice experience.

What's tripping me up is:

> "...embracing this means to not routinely send behavior within messages..."

Can someone give me a concrete example of what they mean by "*sending **behavior** within messages*", and then explain how this is a violation of the "actor model"?

**I'm using the Java API (not Scala), and so I only care about how this relates to Java 8.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A concrete example using Java 8:

```
class MyActor extends AbstractActor {
  public MyActor(ActorRef someOther) {
    final Props props = Props.create(SomeActor.class);
    final PartialFunction<Object, BoxedUnit> behavior =
      ReceiveBuilder
        .match(String.class, s -> getContext().actorOf(props, s))
        .build();

    receive(ReceiveBuilder
      .matchAny(x -> someOther.tell(behavior, self()))
      .build()
    );
  }
}
```

If the Actor referenced by `someOther` were to execute the behavior that we sent to it, then it would using *our* ActorContext, not its own. This will result in undefined behavior, it breaks the encapsulation. One Actor *must not* invoke any method on another Actor, ever. Only then can we guarantee that within an Actor you can program single-threadedly, without needing any synchronization primitives (like `synchronized` or locks/semaphores).

Comment: Ahhh, thanks @RolandKuhn makes perfect sense.  Actors can never invoke other actor method directly; they must use immutable messages for invoking the desired functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Don't send a function ("behavior") within a message because you might close over the internal state of another actor.

Comment: Thanks @Ryan (+1) - please see my update, as I should have specified that I am using the Java API and *not* Scala. Can you provide a concrete example in Java? I'm still not seeing the forest through the trees.

Comment: Java 8 lambdas are functions, "function" does not at all imply Scala.